# how to configure chrome developer tool not to debug all extension scripts

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I have opened `Enable frameworks debugging support` flag in chrome experiments. There was a pattern used to skip stepping through scripts. As there were a lot of chrome Extensions, I could hardly type them all with `or` logic operator in the pattern input. Is there a flag used  to skip all extension scripts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can star the bug at http://crbug.com/160207 to follow the progress.

Blackbox feature in Chrome: http://crbug.com/267592

Meanwhile, just add this regex pattern to blackbox all content scripts: `^chrome-extension://`

Comment: Thanks you!And the regex pattern seems to be `^chrome-extension:\/\/`

Comment: @chestnut: do not forget to accept answers that answer your questions best

Comment: There's now a "Blackbox content scripts" checkbox to accomplish this in the Blackboxing settings area.

Comment: Dont know whats going on but now in 2019, that issue is fixed, yet still does not work for me. Only thing that works is the suggestion to blackbox `^chrome-extension://` Surely this must mean something weird on my local, as nobody else seems to have this? Anyone? The script file actually has the header saying its blackboxes, but still keeps stopping on it during debugger use.

Comment: @redfox05 Without the regex it doesn't work for me either.

Comment: @RenéK good to know thanks. I also have to do this in the console, to avoid error messages from extensions wasting hours of my time hunting down bugs that are not even in my app.